# How can I save rows of rich text box in different rows in SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, richtextbox

i have created a method and calling it on a save button. I want to save all rows of rich text box in different rows respectively in SQL database. Instant help will be appreciated.

```
private void SaveData() 
{
    xConn.Open();
    new SqlCommand("insert into tbldata values('"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+"','"+richTextBox1.Text+"')", xConn).ExecuteNonQuery();
    xConn.Close();                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *even* iterate every line in your richtextbox. You just inserting it's current text. You can use it's [`Lines` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns the lines of text as a string array.

Also don't insert your `DateTime` values with their string representaiton. Insert their values *directly* to your [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). BTW, this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

You should always consider to your right data type for your column types. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

```
private void SaveData() 
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbldata values(@date, @text)";
        string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;

        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            // Change your first column type to datetime or datetime2
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = line;
            // I assume your second column is nvarchar

            if(con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
               con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }             
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand your code may be because i am a beginner. Although i have copied your code and pasted in my app but it is now giving an error 4 times it is saying expected ; and NewLine in Constant near:values(@date, @text)";

Comment: @SyedAliAhmed Don't just copy and paste code. Understand it first and adapt it to your own connection and command.

Comment: Error2'System.Data.SqlDbType' does not contain a definition for 'Datetime'

Comment: Error 1 The name 'conString' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @SyedAliAhmed Sorry it should be `DateTime` not `Datetime`. C# is case sensitive. And paste your connection string to `conString` part of the code.

Comment: Actually sir i want to show this app as a demo to my client that's why i am in a rush and copying code. So please just help me out with these 2 errors and i will understand that code today after that..